# Obtaining IP Address Cycles - Wireless Connection Failing Troubleshooting

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, troubleshooting, windows-server-2012

We are trying to connect wirelessly to our business' network through our router (BT Business Hub). It was working a week or two ago and as far as I am aware nothing has changed. Anything trying to connect to the wireless cycles 'Obtaining IP' indefinitely.

Now, I am not a trained network admin by any means so I don't really know how to trouble shoot this. The DHCP server has not exceeded it's address pool, but does the Scope Option 'Router' have to match the current router handing out IPs? At the moment it matches our Netgear firewall.

When I run ipconfig /all on a laptop connected directly to the router the default gateway is returned as the IP of the firewall, so I can't find a way to access the router settings to check them.

Any ideas for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is in this position in Future I will detail how I got around this. We were using BT Business Hub routers and after some searching I found the IP address I needed to access it, after finding a way to list all the gateways.

After logging into the router all I did was go to the settings section and navigated to the Wireless tab, where I found the following

> Wireless Channel
>
> If you’re having problems with poor wireless range or speed, first click on the ‘Refresh’ button. Your Hub will search again for the best channel. (Please wait approximately one minute for your Hub to automatically pick the new channel.)
>
> Refresh <--Button

Clicking Refresh resolved the issue.